Highway thriller movie about a car driver followed/chased by a monster truck
A car driver is followed/chased by a monster truck. It happened in a desert road. I don't remember the monster driver intention. but I think he is upset because the car driver preceded him. Then the monster truck driver followed the car driver to anywhere he went. I remember the car driver visited gas station, snake farm, a car junkyard.  
I'm sure it is 2000's and in English.

Could be The Duel https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duel_(1971_film)

@FranciscoV. It's almost certainly Duel (no 'The'). You should upgrade that to an answer. "the car driver visited gas station," Yep. He stopped there for lunch, thinking he'd lost the crazed truck driver, only to see the truck parked outside. He then presumed the driver was in the diner and started accusing people, only to get roughed up and tossed out, and then find out that the driver had never entered the diner. "snake farm, a car junkyard." From memory, these two were a single place. But "sure it is 2000's" Nope. 1970s. Directed by Steven Spielberg,

I agree. I think it's Duel. I don't realize the year difference is so huge. Sorry guys

@FranciscoV. We have a winner! Please upgrade the comment so the OP can give you the 'tick' of acceptance. :)

You are looking for Duel from 1971, which is the full-length film directing debut of Steven Spielberg.
From Wikipedia:

Duel is a 1971 television (and later full-length theatrical) thriller film directed by Steven Spielberg in his full-length film directing debut and written by Richard Matheson, based on Matheson's short story of the same name. It stars Dennis Weaver as a terrified motorist stalked on a remote and lonely road by the mostly unseen driver of a mysterious tanker truck.

From Andrews comment:

It's almost certainly Duel ... "the car driver visited gas station," Yep. He stopped there for lunch, thinking he'd lost the crazed truck driver, only to see the truck parked outside. He then presumed the driver was in the diner and started accusing people, only to get roughed up and tossed out, and then find out that the driver had never entered the diner. "snake farm, a car junkyard." From memory, these two were a single place. But "sure it is 2000's" Nope. 1970s. Directed by Steven Spielberg,

You can watch the trailer here, the snake can be seen around 0:43s:





By any chance it can be Joy Ride 3 aka Joy Ride 3: Road Kill ?
From IMDb:

A group of hotheaded street racers are on their way to the Road Rally 1000. As they drive through a desolate shortcut on the way to the race, a man starts tracking, teasing and torturing them until the end of the road.

Trailer:



It also have two previous installation with similar story: Joy Ride (2001) and Joy Ride 2: Dead Ahead aka Roadkill 2.

No, It's not the movie I am looking for. I remember the movie focused on a fear of being followed by somebody. I think no or not many action in the movie
